# I am having trouble with comparing datetimes, when there are DB, Go and Unix versions

Tags: go

So, basically a person has a shift, with a start time and duration, and I need to know how many minutes to go.

I retrieve a standard string from the database ([MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)) of datetime for the start of the shift (for example, 2022-01-01 09:00:00).
I also retrieve the number of hours of the shift (for example, 8).
I can then determine current time, using Go's Time.time, but this format is different.

Please see code below, which explains the problem better, and gives the pieces missing.

```
var shiftStartDB string // For example 2022-01-01 09:00:00
var shiftStartUnix int // For example, start time converted to minutes since epoch
var offTimer int // Number of hours for the shift
var shiftEndDB string // For example 2022-01-01 17:00:00
var shiftEndUnix int // For example, end time converted to minutes since epoch
var nowTime Time.time // Go's version of time for now
var nowUnix int // Go has now converted to Unix time
var templateID string
var minsToGo int

_ = db.QueryRow("SELECT LastSignedOn, OffTimer, TemplateID FROM assets WHERE ID = ?", assetid).Scan(&shiftStartDB, &offTimer, &templateID)
shiftStartUnix = <convert database time into unix time>
if offTimerTemp == 0 {
    _ = db.QueryRow("OffTimer FROM templates WHERE ID = ?", templateID).Scan(&offTimer)
}
shiftEndUnix = shiftStartUnix + (offTimer * 60)
nowTime = time.Now()
nowUnix = <convert Go time into Unix time>
minsToGo = shiftEndInt - nowInt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nowUnix = nowTime.UNIX()/60`, as `Time.UNIX` returns the number of seconds elapsed since epoch. That said, this might be easier to deal with if you parsed the times and used go library time functions directly:

```
shiftStartTime,err := time.Parse("2006-02-01 15:04:05",dbTime)
shiftEnd=shiftStartTime.Add(time.Hour*offTimer)
minsToGo:=shiftEnd.Sub(time.Now()).Minutes()
```